# Laravel Socialite can't be installed in upgraded version 5.6

Tags: laravel

[image]

I have upgraded the laravel from 5.5 to 5.6 and try to install laravel/socialite but there is error.

Composer.json
[image]

Comment: show your composer.json file

Comment: is that enough? or I will show everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the autoloader is jammed up and needs to be cleared.

Try running

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan clear-compiled`
3. `composer require laravel/socialite`

Comment: your errors are in your screenshot are not matching what is listed in your screenshot of composer.json

Comment: did you already run `composer update` after updating the composer.json because your screenshot of the error saying you did not and your file system is still 5.5 along with PHP Unit is still on 6.5

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install the version ^3.2.0 for the package if you are using laravel 5.6, not the ^3.0 or ^4.0 so, you need to be explicit about the version:

```
composer require laravel/socialite "^3.2.0"
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite#installation